# Zhonyas on Lee Sin?

Tags: league-of-legends

I've recently watched a video of a guy playing LS (Gripex specifically) and there's a part where he has a Zhonya.

I know it requires skill playing LS, so if handled properly: what are the pros/cons of Zhonya's on LS? Is the build situational?

Answer (score 6):

Zhonyas is not a good item on Lee Sin.
The only use it has is the 50 bonus armor and the active. The AP are simply useless, because the only AP scaling is on his shield and is quite poor.
As Lee the only use for the active is, when you go in and Insec someone, but know you need your team to catch up and you will get killed very fast by their backline. But this also means that you play full AD because if you are tanky it will be no problem for you to stand in the backline.

But even in this situation there are better items like GA or QSS that give you even more tankiness or damage and self-protection in fights.
And if you are a good Lee Sin it shouldnt be a big problem to kick more than one enemy into the air and you can stay pretty safe this way.

The most positive aspect in building Zhonyas on Lee are the style points when you activate it while you kick.

Comment: I would not suggest QSS on Lee sin unless you're up against a heavily CC team. Merc Treads would be considered a better alternative. If it's magic resist that is desired, a banshee veil would be better or if you have a ravenous hydra/bloodthirster, a spirit visage synergies well.. Gripex most definitely went for the style points however.

Comment: The shield has an 80% AP scaling, that's not really "quite poor", quite the opposite. That's at the top of AP scalings for shield abilities across all champions, with only Shen ult having higher scaling. Just saying.